# Firestore Write Data Missing sometimes

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are using Firebase firestore with our simple grocery delivery app (android) for more than a year. Its super fast and great but it keeps missing data while writing.
Before, without using `transactions` and `batched writes`, the problem was much more persistent(about 10/1000 entries). After using the issue has been reduced but not completely gone(about 2/1000 entries).

**Scenario:**
We have few collections which are set/updated when the product is added namely `products`,`stock`and `daylogs`. When we add/update the product, the transaction writes different data to all these collections. But sometimes(2/1000), the transaction is successful and writes to `products` and `stock` but not `daylogs`.

*Here  is a simpler version of the code. Although, I don't think it's a code issue because it works fine 99% of the time.*

```
  firebasefirestore.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {

                DocumentReference thisProduct = rootRef.collection("products").document(docId);
                DocumentReference thisStock = rootRef.collection("stock").document(docId);
                DocumentReference logs = rootRef.collection("daylogs").document(LogDocumentId);

                transaction.update(thisProduct, data);
                transaction.update(thisStock, data);
                transaction.update(logs, data);

                String complete = "1";
                return  complete;
            }

        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                if (result.equals("1")) {
                  Toast.makeText(AddProduct.this, "Data Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } 
            }
        });
```

Why is this happening? And How can this be solved?

Sorry for my english.
Please help.

Comment: Haven't you asked the same question before?

Comment: @TarikHuber The question was closed because I hadn't added any code.

Comment: Ah yes. For me that is no reason. It is a very general issue that doesn't matter much on code.